# How to convert a unicode string to the corresponding ascii string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, ascii

This code:

```
print u'S\xe9parateur'
str(u'S\xe9parateur')
```

throws the error:

```
Séparateur
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I used the function str because I want to convert the unicode string `u'S\xe9parateur'` to the corresponding ascii string, i.e `u'S\xe9parateur'` --> `'S\xc3\xa9parateur'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a corresponding ASCII string, it's a UTF-8 string. ASCII, definitionally, cannot represent the whole of the Unicode range; UTF-8 can.

To perform the conversion, use the `.encode` method of `unicode` objects:

```
u'S\xe9parateur'.encode('utf-8')
```

produces `'S\xc3\xa9parateur'`.

Comment: Works! But I'm confused, I thought that unicode variables in python2 are encoded in utf-8 ??

Comment: @data The encoding of Unicode variables is an internal detail you shouldn't have to worry about (and don't have to if you switch to Python 3.3+).  In reality, it is either UTF-16LE (narrow build) or UTF-32LE (wide build) and the length of the Unicode string is affected by how many code units it takes to represent the code point.  This is a [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) that is fixed in Python 3.3+.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Pedantic note: Prior to 3.3, the underlying data was UCS2 or UCS4, not UTF-16 or UTF-32. The distinction is important because it meant that narrow builds couldn't use non-BMP characters at all (non-BMP characters are representable in UTF-16, which can represent them as a pair of 16 bit values, but UCS2 is fixed length; all characters must be exactly 16 bits/2 bytes). The per-code point overhead of a `unicode` object in Py2 is always a fixed multiple of the number of code points, 2 for narrow builds, 4 for wide builds.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: The fix in Python 3.3 fixed the major issues with the old approach. It removed the distinction between narrow and wide builds (so all versions of Python can handle [non-BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29) characters, not just wide builds), while reducing the memory use for low ordinal value strings. Strings encodable in ASCII or latin-1 needs only one byte per character, BMP strings need two bytes per character, and only non-BMP strings use four bytes per character, so for the Python internal names (almost exclusively ASCII), memory overhead is minimal.

Comment: @dada: As an added note to the above, on Python 2, `unicode` objects are either UCS2 or UCS4 all the time, and if used with the old-style buffer protocol (the `buffer` type, removed in Python 3 in favor of `memoryview`, which doesn't support Py3 `str` [equivalent to Py2 `unicode`] because trying to use logically text data as binary byte buffers causes all sorts of problems [which is why `str` and `bytes` were separated in Py3 in the first place]), they also store a cached `str` encoded with whatever `sys.getdefaultencoding()` reports (which is often ASCII; you can't rely on UTF-8).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Pedantic note.  Python 2 narrow builds use UTF-16LE.  `s = u'\U00010FAC'` is outside the BMP but `len(s)` is 2 because it uses UTF-16 surrogates.  Definitely not UCS2.  UTF-32 is a subset of UCS4 (supports U+0000 to U+10FFFF only).  For example `s = u'\U00110000'` doesn't work.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: Huh. I don't have a narrow build around to test, I'd been basing my statement on [this part of the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/unicode.html#c.Py_UNICODE), but the wording there is a little weird; UCS2 characters could still mean UTF-16 strings I guess. Checking source code, it's doing high/low surrogates, so non-BMP is ([sorta](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/#rationale)) supported. It's not guaranteed little-endian (the source code accepts a define to compile big endian), but yeah, the default is little-endian and likely to be the case on most builds.

Comment: Windows Python 2 is narrow build.  I'm glad Python 3.3 came along.